# Install a python module ignoring version requirement

Tags: python, windows, pip, easy-install, pyside2

Is there a way to use pip, easy install or any other method to ignore Python version requirements when installing a module?

I'd like to use the unofficial wheel for PySide2 with Python 3.6 despite it being for version 3.5 as my code has problems with 3.5.

Several issues with Visual Studio are making it impossible for me to compile everything from scratch.

Comment: Download the python package version you want and run `python setup.py install` from your shell. This is unofficial way.

Comment: There's no wheel for 3.6, it's only for 3.5.

Comment: Yes, but you wanted to forcefully install it and above is the one way I know to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately wheels don't come with setup.py.

Answer (score 3):

(This is an old question, but still relevant--I was looking for the answer today.)

You can pass the parameter `--ignore-requires-python` to pip to override the Python dependency:

`pip install --ignore-requires-python <library>`

See also: [Can I force pip to install a package even with a version conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74728651/can-i-force-pip-to-install-a-package-even-with-a-version-conflict/74728774#74728774)